# Command failed with exit code 1: apkanalyzer manifest target-sdk C:\~ 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program

Tags: cordova

I executed this command >> C:\Users\ransl\Desktop\CordovaProject>cordova emulate android
But I am getting these errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1dju.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.